# my node.js code work unstable in aws-lambda, Sometimes it works fine, sometimes skipping the data persistence that piece of code

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-serverless

The data center uploads a csv file to our S3 bucket every five minutes, which triggers my lambda function to read the file and save the data to DynamoDB. But the code that performs data persistence is not stable, sometimes it will be executed, and sometimes it will be skipped completely. This makes me very confused. Here is my code.

```
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    var csvtojson = require('csvtojson');
    var  encoding = require('text-encoding');
    AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId: '********',
        secretAccessKey: '**********',
        region: 'us-west-2',
        sslEnabled:false
    });

    var s3 = new AWS.S3();
    var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

    exports.handler = async (event) => {
        try {
            console.log(event);
            console.log(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']);
            //get the file name
            let key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'];
            let date = `${key}`.slice(24,36);
            console.log(date);
            let getObject = {Bucket: 'saas-status-mockup-data', Key: `${key}`};
            //get the object
            let response = await s3.getObject(getObject).promise();
            //transfer to csv
            let csvFile= new encoding.TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(response.Body);
            //transfer to json
            let res = await csvtojson().fromString(csvFile);
            console.log(res);
            await res.map(async(item,key) => {
                console.log(item);
                let putParams = {};
                if(item.FARM=="SMAX Internal production Functionalities"){
                    putParams.TableName = 'InternalProductionDb';
                } else if(item.FARM=="SMAX Trial Major Functionalities"){
                    putParams.TableName = 'TrialMajorDb';
                } else {
                    console.error(item);
                }
                putParams.Item = {
                    'Date' : {
                        S:`${date}${item.BUSINESS_PROCESS}`
                    },
                    'StatusId':{
                        S:`${date}${item.BUSINESS_PROCESS}`
                    },
                    'BusinessProcess':{
                        S:`${item.BUSINESS_PROCESS}`
                    },
                    'Status':{
                        S:`${item.STATUS}`
                    }
                };
                console.log(putParams);
                //put data to dynamoDB, But sometimes this code sometimes does not execute.
                let putRes = await ddb.putItem(putParams).promise();
                console.dir(putRes);
            });
        }
        catch(error){
            console.error(error);
            return error;
        }
    };
```

Comment: How do you trigger your lambda? I mean, is it cron job or handler which triggers lambda on new s3 upload?

Comment: @Grynets Aws-lambda itself provides a lot of triggering methods, including when a new file was created in S3's bucket, the file information will be passed to the handler through event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array.map()` returns an array not a Promise so you cannot `await` it (e.g. `await res.map()` in your code).

First, you should collect a list of promises and the use `Promise.all()` to wait for all of them.

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    try {
        console.log(event);
        console.log(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']);
        //get the file name
        let key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'];
        let date = `${key}`.slice(24,36);
        console.log(date);
        let getObject = {Bucket: 'saas-status-mockup-data', Key: `${key}`};
        //get the object
        let response = await s3.getObject(getObject).promise();
        //transfer to csv
        let csvFile= new encoding.TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(response.Body);
        //transfer to json
        let res = await csvtojson().fromString(csvFile);
        console.log(res);

        // Construct the list of promises.
        const promises = res.map((item, key) => {
            console.log(item);
            let putParams = {};
            if(item.FARM=="SMAX Internal production Functionalities"){
                putParams.TableName = 'InternalProductionDb';
            } else if(item.FARM=="SMAX Trial Major Functionalities"){
                putParams.TableName = 'TrialMajorDb';
            } else {
                console.error(item);
            }
            putParams.Item = {
                'Date' : {
                    S:`${date}${item.BUSINESS_PROCESS}`
                },
                'StatusId':{
                    S:`${date}${item.BUSINESS_PROCESS}`
                },
                'BusinessProcess':{
                    S:`${item.BUSINESS_PROCESS}`
                },
                'Status':{
                    S:`${item.STATUS}`
                }
            };
            console.log(putParams);
            //put data to dynamoDB, But sometimes this code sometimes does not execute.
            return ddb.putItem(putParams).promise();
        });

        // Wait for all promises to finish.
        return Promise.all(promises)
    }
    catch(error){
        console.error(error);
        return error;
    }
};
```